# Does FileReader async read methods block the main thread?

Tags: javascript, browser, filereader

I know that async methods are supposed to be non-blocking. But I usually see them aplied to external operations like `fetch()`. *I.e:* things that are processed outside of the browser.

But what about the `FileReader()` API? The file processing is done by the browser, right?

```
const reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = (event) => {
  console.log(event.target.result);
};

reader.onerror = (event) => {
  console.log(event.target.result);
};


// **ONE** OF THE POSSIBLE METHODS BELOW

reader.readAsText(file);
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

**QUESTION**

If I read a 100Gb file, will that block my main thread at some point? I mean, even if it waits for the call stack to be empty before it runs, will this block my main thread whenever it's processing some huge file? How does it work in this case?

Whatever the answer is, does it apply to any method that runs an asynchronous operation that in the end is being processed by the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is "async".

The data HardDrive/memory access etc. will be done in parallel, that's usually what takes the longer time, and for this the browser doesn't need to block the main thread, that's basic I/O operation.

The actual [reading and processing of the binary data](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#readOperation) to whatever format you asked has to be done [**in parallel**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#in-parallel).

> To run steps in parallel means those steps are to be run, one after another, at the same time as other logic in the standard (e.g., at the same time as the event loop). This standard does not define the precise mechanism by which this is achieved, be it time-sharing cooperative multitasking, fibers, threads, processes, using different hyperthreads, cores, CPUs, machines, etc. By contrast, an operation that is to run immediately must interrupt the currently running task, run itself, and then resume the previously running task.

Of course, we can't be sure it will be true parallelism, since the hardware may not support concurrency, but from the specs point of view, it is asynchronous.

Now, reading a 100GB file will certainly just throw an Error stating that you don't have enough memory available. And if you did have enough memory, then there are chances that your computer suffers anyway from such a big chunk of data.
In the same way, the generated data will occupy memory when sent back to your thread through the *.result* property. Dealing with too big data will probably have influence on your page's performance.

Comment: Thanks! So the file processing is not done by the browser Javascript engine? P.S.: The 100gb was really an exageration just to imagine that it would take a long time to process.

Comment: No, it's probably not written in javascript ;-) (though implementors are allowed to do this wherever they want)