# Scoping/Async of FileReader .readAsText and .onload methods to fill array with txt data

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, filereader, onload

Using keypresses P and C for two local .txt file-uploads

readin50.txt which contains string-val "50" & readin60.txt which contains string-val "60"

P-press to upload readin50.txt pushes "50" to `txtDatas`-array

C-press to upload readin60.txt doesn't push "60" subsequently to `txtDatas`-array (but I want it to)

When I run again `reader.readAsText(document.querySelector('#upload').files[0]);` in console it populates `txtDatas`-array with the latest chosen readin##.txt value of "60"

**Press P-key..**

- console.log.. `P key press` (choose readin50.txt ://pozitive-energy.glitch.me/readin50.txt)
- console.log.. `inputBtn called`
- console.log.. `<input type=​"file" id=​"upload">​ 'FILE'`
- console.log.. `checking` (waits for user to choose-a-file-upload)
- console.log.. `50 target.result`
- `txtDatas = ['50']` (ok good)

---

**Press C-key..**

- console.log.. `C key press` (choose readin60.txt ://../readin60.txt)
- console.log.. `<input type=​"file" id=​"upload">​ 'FILE'`
- console.log.. `checking` (waits for users upload file choice)
- console.log.. `50 target.result`
- `txtDatas = ['50', '50']` (want ['50', '60'])

**Run again `reader.readAsText(document.querySelector('#upload').files[0]);`..**

- console.log.. `60 target.result`
- `txtDatas = ['50', '50', '60']` (want ['50', '60'])

Want to push 50 to `txtDatas`-array after upload of readin50.txt and subsequently push 60 to `txtDatas`-array after upload of readin60.txt `['50', '60']`

**global scope..**

```
const reader = new FileReader();
var txtDatas = [];

var simulateClick = function (elem) {
    var evt = new MouseEvent('click', {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
        view: window 
    });
    // If cancelled, don't dispatch our event
    var canceled = !elem.dispatchEvent(evt);
};

var b = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

b.addEventListener("keydown", (evt) => {
    console.log(evt.keyCode); //log keycode
    if(evt.keyCode == "80"){
        console.log("P key press");
        var pbtn = document.getElementById('ifile');
        setTimeout(function(){ simulateClick(pbtn); },200);
        setKeypressChooseFile();
        pbtn.style.display = "none";
    }
});

function setKeypressChooseFile() {
    b.addEventListener("keydown", (evt) => {
        if(evt.keyCode == "67"){
            console.log("C key press");
            setTimeout(function(){ fileRead(document.querySelector('#upload')); },200);
        }
    });
}

//create div and create-button
(function helper() {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = "target_div";
    div.innerHTML = '<p>init</p>';
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    let btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.id ="ifile";
    btn.innerHTML = "PULL";
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
    btn.setAttribute("onclick","inputBtn();");
})();

function fileRead(c) {
    if(c){
        simulateClick(c);
    };
    var file = document.querySelector('#upload');
    console.log(file, "FILE"); //shows file object
    //setInterval to check if file uploaded then clear
    var checkFile = setInterval(() => {
        console.log("checking");
        if (typeof(document.querySelector('#upload').files[0]) == "object") {
            reader.readAsText(document.querySelector('#upload').files[0]);
            reader.onload = res => { console.log(res.target.result, "target.result"); txtDatas.push(res.target.result); }
            reader.onerror = err => console.log(err);
            clearInterval(checkFile);
        }
    }, 1000);
}

function inputBtn() {
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = "file";
    input.id = "upload";
    var simulateClick = function (elem) {
        var evt = new MouseEvent('click', {
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: true,
            view: window
        });
        // If cancelled, don't dispatch our event
        var canceled = !elem.dispatchEvent(evt);
    };

    setTimeout(function(){ simulateClick(input); },200);
    console.log("inputBtn called");
    document.getElementById('target_div').appendChild(input);
    fileRead(false);
}
```

Comment: want to fill `txtDatas` array with "50" and then "60" but can't
first I chose readin50.txt file and push "50" to `txtDatas`
then chose readin60.txt file and it pushes again "50" to `txtDatas`
want that each time I chose readin##.txt file the contents of the file "##" is pushed to `txtDatas` array in order

Comment: Maybe is related to this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56522431/does-filereader-async-read-methods-block-the-main-thread?rq=1

> file processing is not done by the browser Javascript engine